# javascript syntax help required

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on working on a platform where i can insert js code to be used is validated by some compiler and it returns errors for certain cases like

1. `document.write('<IMG ALT="" BORDER="0" NAME="DCSIMG" WIDTH="1" HEIGHT="1" SRC="'+dcsSrc+'">');`

   > **error** * :314:9:document.write can be a form of eval.
2. `parseInt` function throws error if we do  not use the optional radix parameter

Does someone know how the syntax or solution should be????

Comment: The problem seems to be that the platform you are using considers this kind of code to be an error. What platform are you using?

Comment: Are you wanting to write a validator that throws those errors you listed, or are you trying to figure out the syntax to get around those errors?

Comment: @Oded: i was trying to code in a platform that was built by another team, could not modify the platform, so was trying to figure out the syntax to get around these issues as 'kanaka' commented..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These sound like [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) errors messages. You should be able to configure what errors JSLint is checking for. [See the Options section on this page](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html), for more info on what options can be configured, e.g., `tolerate eval`.

Answer (score 1):

Some Javascript implementations refuse to allow document.write because it can be an inherent security issue.

It's always important to use a radix with parseInt.

Here is an example:

```
parseInt("010");      // assumes base 8 because of leading zero
8
parseInt("010", 10);  // force base 10
10
```

Comment: okie....thanks buddy...guess its the compiler issue in the backend of the platform that i was working on.....

Answer (score 0):

Try evaluating this expression outside the write method.

Comment: did not get u...can u give me an example

Answer (score 0):

If the document.write is not working, you can try using:

```
function addElement(dcsSrc) {
  var parentNode = document.getElementById('parentNode');
  var newimg = document.createElement('img');
  newimg.setAttribute('src',dcsSrc);
  newimg.setAttribute('alt','');
  newimg.setAttribute('border','0');
  newimg.setAttribute('name','dcsimg');
  newimg.setAttribute('width','1');
  newimg.setAttribute('height','1');
  parentNode.appendChild(newdiv);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

see:

> http://www.jameswiseman.com/blog/2011/03/31/jslint-messages-document-write-can-be-a-form-of-eval/

solution:

> `document.write("?")` -> `document.body.innerHTML=?`